# Activity to fragment conversion

Tags: android

How to Convert this activity into fragment my problem is that I want to add it my navigational drawer but I dont know how do I need to convert this activity into fragment but how? please help! Thanks

```
package com.google.samples.apps.topeka.activity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.R;
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.FavoriteHelper;


public class Paboritomain extends AppCompatActivity {

    FavoriteHelper mydb;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.paborito_list);
        mydb = new FavoriteHelper(this);
        mydb.getWritableDatabase();

        populateListView();


    }

    private void populateListView(){

        Cursor cursor = mydb.getAllRows();
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {FavoriteHelper.COL_2};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.paboritotext};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.paborito_items,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
        ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_paborito);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);



    }





}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow community. It's better to post your code in code snippet not the code screenshot while asking question.

Comment: please post the actual code, otherwise your question is likely to continue being downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fragment are use Like this...**

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

return rootview;
}
}
```